# Как получить максимальное значение из одной таблицы для каждой строки из другой?

Tags: mysql

Есть две условные таблицы

Workers:

```
id | name   | qualification  
1  | Alex   | 1  
2  | Max    | 2  
3  | George | 4  
4  | Felix  | 1
```

Orders:

```
id | worker_id | category_id | price
1  | 1         | 1           | 300.00
2  | 2         | 2           | 450.00
3  | 3         | 2           | 450.00
4  | 4         | 1           | 300.00
5  | 1         | 1           | 300.00
```

Как для каждой категории из таблицы Orders получить рабочего с максимальной квалификацией?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
  o.category_id,
  w.id as worker,
  max(w.qualification)
FROM
  orders o
  LEFT JOIN workers w ON o.worker_id = w.id
group by
  o.category_id
```

Comment: большое спасибо!